# Magento 2 Checkout not showing all fields

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am using Magento 2.0 and when I added old database data (from Magento1), some fields on checkout page just doesn't show. I checked Admin panel to see if there is anything wrong with Customer data or Checkout, Shipping, but it seems just fine.

Under Shipping Address, only Email address field, First name and Last name show. It is also mixed up, label is last name, but validation says: Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com) - so it is definitely type email.

In console, there are no errors.

Did it happen to anyone before?

Comment: How you added old database from M1 to M2?