# Magento 2 Checkout not showing first name

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1

I've used the migration tool to import data from a Magento 1 site into a new Magento 2 site. Just a slight problem, on the checkout there is no First Name field for either shipping or billing address.

I'm also missing the title for the section:

```
<div class="step-title">Enter delivery name and address</div>
```

Similar to:
[Magento 2 Checkout not showing all fields](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136062/magento-2-checkout-not-showing-all-fields)

Any ideas how I can restore this field?

Comment: Cannot save address in account area either, it has the field for firstname but wont save it: "firstname is a required field."

Answer (score 5):

Alright, I've found the solution to this problem.

You need to edit the `customer_eav_attribute` table, specifical`attribute_id` that corresponds to the first name attribute in your `eav_table`. For me it was the attribute with the ID 23. To show it on the checkout page set the column `is_visible` to `1`, in my situation it was set to `0`, what caused it not to show up on the checkout page.

Hope it helps someone who has a similar problem.

Comment: after migration, for me there was no row for firstname in 'customer_form_attribute' table, i inserted it manually.

Answer (score 2):

So turned out the main attributes tables had attributes in a different order and thus with different IDs. But the table that assigned attributes to forms had the IDs from a clean install.

I converted the IDs to match the attributes table and the fields were restored.

Comment: Can you please tell me where that table is, which assigns the IDs to the form, because I am facing the same issue as you!

Comment: I think it was the eav_form_element table, but eventually I started again and copied data using csv

Comment: I've found the table, and it seems that the attributes are all there (first name is always there for every table ID). I really don't know what is causing the problem here...

Comment: @brance Could you tell me how you solved it as the above solutions are not working for my case too.

Answer (score 0):

In our case first name was not displayed in chekout section after M1 migration. Solution was on table mgap_customer_eav_attribute_website, for us first name field was id=20, selecting it and define as visible and required solved the issue. Thanks to Mageplaza for finding the solution.