# first name field not shows in checkout page magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

When I go to the checkout page, there is no first name field.
I also check this question [Magento 2 Checkout not showing first name](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151121/magento-2-checkout-not-showing-first-name).
In my database, `is_visible` is 1 for `firstname`.